# R: Using gam::gam with lapply on list of variables

Tags: r, gam

I would like to apply different logistic models to a list of variables in a dataframe. The functions `glm()` and `lme4::glmer()` as well as `mgcv::gam()` work without problems. But the function `gam::gam()` I can not use with lapply.

Example:

```
n <- 1000                                                                                            
y <- rbinom(n,1,0.2)                                                                                 
x1 <- rnorm(n)                                                                                       
x2 <- rnorm(n)                                                                                       
xlist  <- list("x1", "x2")                                                                           
df <- data.frame(y, x1, x2)                                                                          

library(gam)

#doesn't work                                                                                                     
gam_list <- lapply(xlist, function(x){                                                              
  gam::gam(substitute(y ~ s(i), list(i = as.name(x))), data = df, family = binomial)                
})      
#Error in terms.default(formula, gam.slist, data = data) :
#no terms component nor attribute

gam <- gam(y ~ s(x1), data = df, family =binomial)
```

Any ideas how to fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `get` here like below, it should work or `eval(parse(text=x))` instead of `get`:

```
gam_list <- lapply(xlist, function(x){                                                              
  gam::gam(y ~ s(get(x)), data = df, family = binomial)                
})
```

**Output**:

```
[[1]]
Call:
gam::gam(formula = y ~ s(get(x)), family = binomial, data = df)

Degrees of Freedom: 999 total; 995 Residual
Residual Deviance: 1010.515 

[[2]]
Call:
gam::gam(formula = y ~ s(get(x)), family = binomial, data = df)

Degrees of Freedom: 999 total; 994.9997 Residual
Residual Deviance: 1011.254
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much for your answer. It works as intendet!

Answer (score 1):

You can also convert a string to a formula.

```
gam_list <- lapply(xlist, function(x) 
            gam::gam(as.formula(sprintf('y~s(%s)', x)), data = df, family = binomial))

gam_list

#[[1]]
#Call:
#gam::gam(formula = as.formula(sprintf("y~s(%s)", x)), family = binomial, data = df)

#Degrees of Freedom: 999 total; 995 Residual
#Residual Deviance: 984.8362 

#[[2]]
#Call:
#gam::gam(formula = as.formula(sprintf("y~s(%s)", x)), family = binomial, data = df)

#Degrees of Freedom: 999 total; 995.0002 Residual
#Residual Deviance: 985.5421
```